# How to know only n number of threads running per second using RateLimiter

Tags: multithreading, java.util.concurrent, rate-limiting

I am doing a simple demo implementation to understand RateLimiter.

I did a simple class, it showing multiple threads running in a second.

If you check in output, 2nd Second, it showing thread-6 also started without completion of thread-2 and Thread-7.

If I am wrong, please help me how RateLimiter works. What changes I have to do in below class to understand RateLimiter behavior.

My code is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

public class RLClient2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(2);
        DT dt = new DT();
        dt.setDaemon(true);
        dt.start();
        T t[] = new T[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = new  T(rateLimiter);
            t[i].start();
        }
    }
}

class T extends Thread {
    RateLimiter rateLimiter = null;

    T(RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
        this.rateLimiter = rateLimiter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        rateLimiter.acquire();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            try {
                sleep(100);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Completed..........");
    }
}


class DT extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("-----------------" + i + " Seconds...");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-----------------0 Seconds...
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-2
Thread-7
Thread-2
Thread-7
Thread-2
Thread-7
Thread-2
Thread-7
Thread-2
Thread-7
-----------------1 Seconds...
Thread-2
Thread-6
Thread-7
Thread-2
Thread-6
Thread-7
Thread-2
Thread-2 Completed..........
Thread-7
Thread-6
Thread-6
Thread-7
Thread-7
Thread-6
Thread-5
Thread-6
Thread-7
Thread-5
Thread-7
Thread-7 Completed..........
Thread-6
Thread-5
Thread-6
Thread-5
Thread-6
Thread-6
Thread-5
-----------------2 Seconds...
Thread-6
Thread-4
Thread-5
Thread-6
Thread-6 Completed..........
Thread-5
Thread-4
Thread-5
Thread-4
Thread-4
```

Answer (score 1):

The RateLimiter imposes restrictions on the RATE not the number of permits. A RateLimiter issues permits at a specific rate. It will never stop issuing permits.

Think of it like this: if you set a rate of 10/sec, then rateLimiter.acquire() will return every 100ms (because 10*100 = 1000ms). You can call it 5000 times and it will return 5000 times, it will just take 5000*100 = 50000ms to return.

So essentially you are implementing a limit on the speed with which new threads are created, not the total number of threads that can be created.

[Read the documentation here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) to see the details. The very first sentence explains the behavior:

> A rate limiter. Conceptually, a rate limiter distributes permits at a
>   configurable rate. Each acquire() blocks if necessary until a permit
>   is available, and then takes it. Once acquired, permits need not be
>   released.

The next sentence of the API documentation reveals how you can limit the total number (as opposed to the rate):

> Rate limiters are often used to restrict the rate at which some
>   physical or logical resource is accessed. **This is in contrast to
>   Semaphore which restricts the number of concurrent accesses instead of
>   the rate** (note though that concurrency and rate are closely related,
>   e.g. see Little's Law).

By the way, if you need a fixed number of threads collaborating on something I highly recommend not doing it with custom code. Instead have a look at Executors and use [newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) instead.